# I need to find how many years between the date? python 3

Tags: python-3.5

I need to find how many years between the date?

```
Input

dat = ['Apr 2010', 'Dec 2012']

output like this

{
    total_years = 2.8
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but it'll work

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("Apr 2010", "%b %Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec 2012", "%b %Y")

diff = (end - start).days // 365
```